# Pagination Pages increment 2 more blank page

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am sorry if the question is very basic or someone might post this question before but i can't figure out this code. Any help appreciated

Pagination works good but it shows 2 more blank pages even there are no posts on that page.

php:

```
 <?php

     $page = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
      $perpage = 10;
    //$limit = ($page > 1) ? (((($page *2)+1)-3)* $perpage) - $perpage : 0;
     $limit = ((($page*2)+1)-3)*$perpage;

       $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM test WHERE Category='Pharma' LIMIT {$limit}, {$perpage}");
    $records = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

      $total = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total");
      $total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total)['total'];

 $pages = ceil($total/$perpage);
    ?>
        //prev 
        <?php 
    if($page>1){
         ?>
     <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php $pagep = $page -1; echo $pagep; ?>" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
   <?php
     }
      ?>
        //next
        <?php 
             if($page<$pages){
            ?>
           <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php $pagen = $page +1; echo $pagen; ?>">Next</a>
                        <?php
         }
       ?>
```

I tried to change the query as i know i fetch $total up here not the $query but when i fetch $query pagination not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LIMIT ($page-1) * $perpage,$perpage` in your SQL query ?

Comment: These two errors shown!

Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\finaltest.php on line 257

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\finaltest.php on line 264